# sending email not working with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, sendmail

I built an example app to try to make the mailer work. The app is hosted on https://blooming-brushlands-80122.herokuapp.com,
and the source code is [here](https://github.com/Hajar1/mailExample). Here's my config associated with action mailer:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
```

and for sending the mailer

```
 def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save

          # Sends email to user when user is created.
          ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver

          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

The app does not send emails to users.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: LESS YELLING PLEASE

Comment: changed the title *_*

Comment: Post your code for sending the mailer as well as your  config file

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using the free sendgrid Addon from Heroku since I see you're using sendmail.  To add it just log into heroku and add it as a free resource.  Since you didn't specify whether or not your trying to send emails locally or in production I added configs for both.  In your config/environment/development.rb file you should do the following to send from your local:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp  #Yours used sendmail, change to this.
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true #Needed if this is dev env. file
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['KUNZIG_SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['KUNZIG_SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'localhost:3000',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Obviously replace the username and password with your own env. variables assigned by Heroku.  Heroku's config. vars can be found under the settings tab. just click the "reveal" button.

Your environment/production.rb file would be something like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'kunzig.herokuapp.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Notice the only change is the domain name and environment variables since these are set automatically by Heroku when you add Sengrid as an addon.  Also, change your `deliver` call in your controller to `deliver_now` so we know it's not a problem with your background worker config.

Comment: heyyy, tried what u said still doesn't send :/ I pushed the changes u request to github as well

Comment: Are you testing your app on heroku or the app locally?

Comment: on heroku :) It's up and running and even and the logs show no errors but the emails are not being received you can find the app here https://blooming-brushlands-80122.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Don't push to github then lol push to heroku!  Run "git add -A", then "git commit -m 'Added config changes for email", then "git push heroku master"

Comment: hahahaha i integrated heroku github. Good news it works! but the account got suspended lol. Since i was trying to send so many emails to my self hahaha Thank you for your help!!!!